# pop-up modal for all instances of the google sheet that are open - google apps script or drive api

Tags: google-apps-script, modal-dialog, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a a google sheet that functions as a front-end to allow some less technical users the ability to view and make minor changes to a table.  I have written a script to connect to our sql database to be able to read from the table and allow an update to the sql table based on edits to the google sheet.  Occasionally there may need to be batch updates to the table made on the sql server.  I currently have a flow of:

- Trigger loadingmodal () which has pop up to let user know data is
  being refreshed with this message: "This box will close when the data
  has finished loading."
- loadingmodal() calls readFromTable to refresh the google sheet from
  the sql server.
- It takes about a minute to read from the database and populate the
  data on the spreadsheet.
- Modal Closes and users can resume editing.

All works as it should, except that the modal doesn't appear when using the installed trigger on a timer (every few hours), it only functions when manually calling the function from the script editor, and in that case it only shows for the user that is calling, rather than all users who have the sheet open.

I am looking into the google drive API but figured I'd throw this out to anyone else that may be looking for a similar solution.

Code.gs:

```
function loadingModal () {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('loading.html')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(200)
    .setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Loading Data...');
}


function readFromTable() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var conn = getConnection();
  var start = new Date();
  Logger.log('Started', start);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM stage_printfile');
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  var header = [];
  var resultArray = [];


  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
    header.push(results.getMetaData().getColumnName(col + 1));

  }
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,1,numCols).setValues([header]);

  while (results.next()) {
    var tempString = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      tempString.push(results.getString(col + 1));  
    }
    resultArray.push(tempString);
    tempString = [];
  }

  var dataRange = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, resultArray.length, numCols);
  dataRange.setValues(resultArray);

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);

}

function writeToTable () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var value = ss.getActiveCell().getValue();
  var col = ss.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var colName = ss.getRange(1, col).getValue();
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var checknum = ss.getRange(row, 2).getValue();

  var conn = getConnection();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.execute("UPDATE stage_printfile set " + colName + " = '" + value + "' WHERE CheckNo = " + checknum);



}
```

loading.html:

```
<style>
@keyframes spinner {
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.spinner {
    min-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
}

.spinner:before {
    content: 'Loading…';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    margin-left: -13px;
}

.spinner:not(:required):before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-color: #c33;
    animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
}

.spinner {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.loadbox {
  display:flex;
  font: bold 14px/18px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
</style>
<div class="loadbox">
<p> This box will close when the data has finished loading.</p><br />
<div class="spinner"></div>
</div>


<script>
  window.onload = function() {    
    //console.log('window.onload ran!');
    parent.document.getElementById('userHtmlFrame').style.overflowY = "hidden";
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(closeDialog)
      .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
        alert(error);
      })
      .readFromTable();
  }

  window.closeDialog = function() {
    google.script.host.close();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is impossible. The function that you trigger with a timer open the spreadsheet by its own separately from the opened versions of the other client. It's not triggered for every opened session.
So it won't display the the popup in their view, but only in it's own view (that no one can see).
You should have a look at the [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) page on the google apps script documentation.
A workaround should be to ask the user install the trigger by their own:
You can create a function that they will launch (asking them some autorisations). The function will  will create the trigger for your other function. So then it will be their account the one that fire the triggered function, and they will see it.